# Need a cleaner way to close dropdowns when clicked outside of them

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, use-effect

I am looking for a cleaner way to close my three dropdowns when I click outside of them.  Currently, I am utilizing `window.addEventListener('click')` with some exclusions to get this done.  While it works decently, I do get random errors saying that my `event.target` is `undefined`.  I haven't had the best luck at repeating the error either.  Anyway, my current code is below.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        // close dropdown on any click outside of button/dropdown/dropdown options
        // these are simple exclusions from the global click - they include dropdowns, dropdown options, and filter/sort buttons
        window.addEventListener("click", e => {
            if (e.path[4].id.includes('filterSortBar') || 
                e.target.id.includes('maxSlider') ||
                e.target.id.includes('minSlider') ||
                e.target.id.includes('minInputContainer') ||
                e.target.id.includes('maxInputContainer') ||
                e.target.type === 'number' ||
                e.path[4].id.includes('filterButtonsContainer') ||
                e.path[4].id.includes('relativeContainer') || 
                e.target.textContent === 'Relevance' || 
                e.target.textContent === 'Retailers' &&
                !e.target.className.includes('buttonPadding')){
            } else {
                setAddFilterTruthy(false)
                setSortTruthy(false)
                setPriceTruthy(false)
            }
    })
}, []);
```

The ugliness is glaring.  Basically, if the click does not contain the element, I set the `truthy` value to `false` and the dropdown closes appropriately.

Comment: You can take a look at this library react-popper-tooltip, they handle outside click: https://github.com/mohsinulhaq/react-popper-tooltip#readme

Comment: Enfield Li thanks but I will probably keep my own code to see if I can refactor it some.  It IS a working solution and in this particular project, time is of the essence.  I may circle back.

Comment: Yeah just a remider, React has built in the Dom api, you can handle the mouse event in jsx like so: <div onMouseOver={ () => {} }> </div>, so adding event listener is for one ugly syntax, and two pron to error like you experienced

Comment: Not sure if the "onMouseOutCapture" works in your situation, I am not super familar with the api either :)

Comment: Think of the amount of ````onMouseOver```` I will have sprinkled throughout my ````JSX````.  That gives me more anxiety then explicitly listing them in in ````useEffect```` but there may be something to the error handling portion.  If it reduces the chance of an error, I may test the waters.

Comment: Looking at the source code for react-popper-tooltip, they seemed have dealt with the outside click, take a look at line 123: https://github.com/mohsinulhaq/react-popper-tooltip/blob/master/src/usePopperTooltip.ts

Comment: Interesting.  I have no idea what that ````getLatest()```` function does, so I will have to do some deep diving.